# Modify then concatenate String

Tags: apex, email, string, substring

I have an Email Service that creates Leads from 3rd party vendors. We now want to accept a UTM parameter, but the vendor can’t concatenate. In my class, how can I turn this (which is in the body of the email):

```
Marketing Referrer Content: Facebook
Marketing Referrer Medium: Displaypro
Marketing Referrer Campaign: Q32022_display
Marketing Referrer Source: Google
Marketing Referrer Term: 50Visa
```

Into this:

```
?utm_medium=displaypro&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Q32022_Display&utm_content=facebook&utm_term=50Visa
```

For Additional Context:
Sample Email:

```
A new lead from Lead Gen tool!

Submitted Form Data
Email: testing2@test.com
First Name: Dev2
Last Name: TestLead
Phone: 310-555-5555
Zip Code: 91403
Marketing Referrer Content: Facebook
Marketing Referrer Medium: Displaypro
Marketing Referrer Campaign: Q32022_display
Marketing Referrer Source: Google
Marketing Referrer Term: 50Visa
```

Current Class

```
//Description: This class accepts a a structured email from a 3rd party vendor and attempts to create a new Lead

public class EmailServiceInboundLead implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler{
    public Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email,Messaging.InboundEnvelope env)
    {
        // Create an InboundEmailResult object for returning the result of the Apex Email Service
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
        
        Lead newLead = new Lead();
        newLead.FirstName = emailSearch(email.plainTextBody, 'First Name:');
        newLead.LastName = emailSearch(email.plainTextBody, 'Last Name:');
        newLead.Email = emailSearch(email.plainTextBody,'Email:');
        newLead.PostalCode = emailSearch(email.plainTextBody, 'Postal Code:');
        newLead.Company = 'not provided';
        newLead.Phone = emailSearch(email.plainTextBody,'Phone:');
        newLead.Description = email.plainTextBody;
        
        //variable to hold any errors
        Set <String> apexErrors = new Set<String>();

        try{
            insert newLead;
        } catch(DmlException e){
            apexErrors.add(e.getMessage() + ' Email Body: ' + email.plainTextBody);
        }

        //Use values from the Email to create a new EmailMessage
        EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();
        emailMessage.status = '3'; // email was sent
        emailMessage.subject = email.subject;
        emailMessage.htmlBody = email.htmlBody;
        emailMessage.TextBody = email.plainTextBody;
        String[] toIds = new String[] {newLead.id};
        emailMessage.toIds = toIds;
        
        try{
            insert emailMessage;
        }catch(DmlException e){
            apexErrors.add(e.getMessage() + ' Email Body: ' + email.plainTextBody);
        }

        // Associate the EmailMessage to the Lead
        EmailMessageRelation r = new EmailMessageRelation();
        r.emailMessageId = emailMessage.Id;
        r.relationId = newLead.id;
        r.relationType = 'FromAddress';
        try{
            insert r;
        }catch(DmlException e){
            apexErrors.add(e.getMessage() + ' Email Body: ' + email.plainTextBody);
        }

        //Run Lead assignment Rule
        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.AssignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = TRUE;
        try{
            Database.update(newLead,dmo);
        }catch(DmlException e){
            apexErrors.add(e.getMessage() + ' Email Body: ' + email.plainTextBody);
        }

        //if there were any errors, send to Admin
        if (!apexErrors.isEmpty()) {
            ZocdocEmailUtility.sendAdminEmail('EmailServiceInboundLead Error', String.join(new List < String > (apexErrors), '<br/>'), !Test.isRunningTest());
        }
        
        result.success = true;
        return result;
    }
    
    //Parse through the email body to find a value and return its value
    public static String emailSearch(String emailBody, String type){
        if(String.isEmpty(emailBody)) return null;
        
        String stringLine;
        String returnString;
        
        //Split the email body lines out by returns (\n)
        for(String msgBodyLine : emailBody.split('\n')) {
            
            //if the current line has the text passed into the method in it grab the entire line and assign it to the stringLine variable
            if(!String.isEmpty(msgBodyLine) && msgBodyLine.containsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                stringLine = msgBodyLine;
                system.debug('stringLine = ' + stringLine);
                break;
            } 
        }
        //If the stringLine variable is not null trim the string at the colon which will provide you with a value. 
        if(stringLine != null) {
            system.debug('stringLine search = ' + stringLine);
            returnString = stringLine.split(':')[1].trim(); 

        }
        //return the found STRING
        return returnString;   
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you already have code that parses the lines in the email body: the `emailSearch()` method.

This is already being used by earlier lines in the main code body. Examples:

```apex
newLead.FirstName = emailSearch(email.plainTextBody, 'First Name:');
newLead.LastName = emailSearch(email.plainTextBody, 'Last Name:');
```

I have not looked into the `emailSearch()` code in detail, so this is obviously untested, but I would try to add code somewhere that does something like:

```apex
String UTM = '?';
UTM += 'utm_medium=' + emailSearch(email.plainTextBody, 'Marketing Referrer Medium:');
UTM += '&utm_source=' + emailSearch(email.plainTextBody, 'Marketing Referrer Source:');
...
```

If that does not give you exactly what you need, you may have to tweak the `emailSearch()` code to handle these inputs.

Then do whatever you need to with the `UTM` string

*This is assuming that all of those items in the email body always exist and always will have values. If you want to build it when/if they do not all have values, then you may want to remove the `&` that I hardcoded at the beginning of the second parameter (and assumed to be in the subsequent parameters), then add some code to check for values before adding a `&` and the next parameter.*

Comment: Thanks, this is usable!

Comment: This can probably be improved by using `String.replaceAll()`, since it appears that all of the target parameters start with "Marketing Referrer". E.g. `email.plainTextBody.replaceAll('Marketing Referrer (.*): (.*)\n', 'utm_$1=$2&')`. Not perfect, but it should get you most of the way there.